# asp.net mvc - Pass json data from view to controller to another view

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I request a ajax call from the View Index.cshtml to an action method in HomeController.cs and get json data that I use in Index.cshtml.

Another View Display.cshtml is called using Url.Action() from different anchor tags in Index.cshtml.Depending on the anchor tag clicked, the data will be displayed in Display.cshtml.

Now I have a requirement where the same json(used in Index.cshtml) is needed in  Display.cshtml.
Please let me know the best way to pass the json data with minimal calls to server & data storage on client side.

Thank you.

Ajax call in Index.cshtml

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")", function (json) { ... }
```

Anchor tag in Index.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Display", "Home", new { Name = "Test" })">
```

Call Display.cshtml in HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Display(string Name)
{
   ViewBag.Name = Name;
   return View();
}
```

Comment: presumably you can write the same `$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")", function (json) { ... }` snippet in the Display view.

Comment: Yeah. I can do that.. But the Json formed executes quite a bit of code which I don't want to execute twice - from performance perspective.

Comment: if you're loading a new page then your whole ASP.NET engine starts from scratch every time anyway...web pages are stateless, so every time you refresh the page or go to another page, you have to reload everything. You've got a JSON service which you can share between multiple pages, so use it. That's what it's for. It's perfectly normal and no-one would really consider it inefficient. If that particular call is slow you could employ caching to minimise it, so the webserver might be able to serve the same data again without querying the DB / running the logic, but that's about it.

Comment: Another possibility could be to try and persist it on the client using localstorage or something, but obviously it's not secure and only pertains to a single user in a single browser on a single device, so it would still be run multiple times if lots of users are connecting, at least until they've visited at least once. Plus, depending how often this data changes, you might be forced to execute it again anyway? Also how large is the generated JSON?

Comment: Another thing I suppose you could try and do is pass it to the Display view using the querystring, but again it's not very secure, plus you might run into encoding issues. You could maybe post that data to the Details page in the body, and make Details only accessible via a POST request.

Comment: The last, more radical option is to refactor things so that Details is a partial view, loaded within Index via ajax when required, so that both views can share the same JSON data (downloaded once in the main Index view) since they become part of the same DOM and JS context once the partial view is loaded. But it would create a dependency whereby Details depends on Index to work correctly, which may not be desirable if Details can also be accessed from other places in the app.